# How to add method with parameter in a list

Tags: c#, list, delegates

I have generic delegates.

```
public delegate void Metodo();
public delegate void Metodo<T>(T parametro);
public delegate void Metodo<T, U>(T parametro1, U parametro2);
public delegate void Metodo<T, U, V>(T parametro1, U parametro2, V parametro3);
public delegate void Metodo<T, U, V, W>(T parametro1, U parametro2, V parametro3, W parametro4);
```

And a list:

```
private List<Metodo> ListOfMethods;
```

I add methods without parameters like this:

```
public void Method();
ListOfMethods.Add(Method);
```

How i can add methods with parameters in my list ?

Like this is my whole class.

```
public class ListOfUpdateMethods
{
    public delegate void Metodo();
    public delegate void Metodo<T>(T parametro);
    public delegate void Metodo<T, U>(T parametro1, U parametro2);
    public delegate void Metodo<T, U, V>(T parametro1, U parametro2, V parametro3);
    public delegate void Metodo<T, U, V, W>(T parametro1, U parametro2, V parametro3, W parametro4);

    private List<Metodo> MetodosPreAtualizacao;
    private List<Metodo> MetodosAtualizacao;

    public ListOfUpdateMethods()
    {
        this.MetodosPreAtualizacao = new List<Metodo>();
        this.MetodosAtualizacao    = new List<Metodo>();
    }

    public void AddMetodosPreAtualizacao(Metodo m)
    {
        this.MetodosPreAtualizacao.Add(m);
    }

    public void AddMetodosAtualizacao(Metodo m)
    {
        this.MetodosAtualizacao.Add(m);
    }

    public void ExecutaMetodosPreAtualizacao()
    {
        foreach (var metodos in this.MetodosPreAtualizacao)
            metodos();
    }

    public void ExecutaMetodosAtualizacao()
    {
        foreach (var metodos in this.MetodosAtualizacao)
            metodos();
    }
}
```

I use in Method into a Windows Form:

```
private void UpdadeControl(ListOfUpdateMethods list, Control control)
    {
        list.ExecutaMetodosPreAtualizacao();

        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var action = new Action<ListOfUpdateMethods, Control>(UpdadeControl);
            control.Invoke(action, new object[] { list, control });
        }
        else
        {
            list.ExecutaMetodosAtualizacao();   
        }
    }
```

I'm looking for the best way to write a generic method to update the controls on my form.

Comment: Well, your list can only contain `Metodo` delegates. So, any delegate you want to add to the list has to adhere to the Metodo signature. If you have for example a method with two parameters like `void SomeM(int a, int b)`, and you already know the literal/constant parameter values to be passed, then you could do something like `MetodosdePreAtualizacao.Add( () => { SomeM(4, 2); } )`...

Comment: If you could, how would you use them when you got them back out? How would you know what parameters to give them, or of what types?

Comment: Btw., these delegates already exist as `Action`, `Action<T>`, `Action<T1, T2>` up to , `Action<T1, T2, ... T16>`. See: [Action<T> Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: This list is for update controls in a windows forms.
I don't need return.
I have a foreach to execute all methods.
I answered  you Ed Plunkett?

Comment: @ThiagoSoaresMota No, you didn't answer me. Create a `List<Object>`. Put a bunch of delegates in it of various types, `Metodo`, `Metodo<String, int, double>`, etc. Now loop through the list with a `foreach` and call each delegate in the list. Now how do you figure out what parameters each one needs? It doesn't matter if it's a `List<Metodo>` or a `List<Object>`. You still don't know what parameters each delegate needs when you call it. The declared type of the list doesn't help with that problem, because it is full of *different types*.

Comment: @EdPlunKett All are different. Each method has your parameters list.

Comment: @ThiagoSoaresMota Every method has a different parameter list. Write the code. Show me how you call them. You can edit your question and add the code to it. You can put any of those delegates in a `List<Object>`, just cast it to `Action`, `Action<int, String>`, or whatever the parameter types are.

Comment: @EdPlunKett called like this:
foreach(var method List Method)
method();

Comment: @ThiagoSoaresMota Show me actual code that compiles. Don't just pretend it compiles, and don't think you can fool us that you tried it when you didn't. Go back to Visual Studio and write code that actually compiles and calls all those different methods. At the end of the day, your audience is the compiler, not me. Fooling me won't help you, and you can't fool a compiler.

Comment: @EdPlunKett Ok. The code have words in portuguese ? This is a problem ?

Comment: @ThiagoSoaresMota I prefer dialects of Old Low Norse or West Saxon, but I'm broad-minded.

Comment: @EdPlunKett  done

Comment: @ThiagoSoaresMota `ExecutaMetodosAtualizacao()` only calls methods with no parameters. I asked you to show me how you call a list of methods where some have one parameter, some have three parameters, and some have none. Storing them is easy. How do you call them?

Comment: @EdPlunKett In this version of the code I only make calls without parameters. I intend to make the generics soon. But I have not thought of that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by creating a `List<Action>` and adding invocations of the various delegates.

A `List<Action>` could contain any sort of action, not just one of these delegates. If you encapsulate the list you can ensure that only the types of actions you want get added.

```
public class MetodoList
{
    private readonly List<Action> _metodos = new List<Action>();

    public void Add(Metodo metodo)
    {
        _metodos.Add(metodo.Invoke);
    }

    public void Add<T>(Metodo<T> metodo, T argument)
    {
        _metodos.Add(() => metodo.Invoke(argument));
    }

    public void Add<T, U>(Metodo<T, U> metodo, T thing, U uther)
    {
        _metodos.Add(() => metodo.Invoke(thing, uther));
    }

    // more of these.

    public void InvokeAll()
    {
        _metodos.ForEach(m => m.Invoke());
    }
}
```

While I don't know what this is for, here's how you would use it:

```
var metodos = new MetodoList();
var target = new HasMetodos();
metodos.Add(target.DoSomething);
metodos.Add(target.DoSomethingWithTwoArguments, "x", 1);
metodos.InvokeAll();
```

Comment: I do not understand why you put the methods in the stack the way you put them. When do you add them or only when InvokeAll () is called?

Comment: @ThiagoSoaresMota I was trying to demonstrate, in a very general sense, how we would create a collection of actions that called methods with different parameters, and how to constrain those methods to match a predetermined set of signatures. And then, having that list of actions, how we would invoke them. That seems related to what you were asking, but I suppose I could be way off.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a list of MulticastDelegate. For example:

```
List<MulticastDelegate> multicastDelegates = new List<MulticastDelegate>();

multicastDelegates.Add(new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")));
multicastDelegates.Add(new Action<int>(x => Console.WriteLine(x)));

foreach (var multicastDelegate in multicastDelegates)
{
    if (multicastDelegate is Action<int> actionInt)
    {
       actionInt(1);
    }
    else if (multicastDelegate is Action action)
    {
       action();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to pass the parameter preferentially next to the method. It would be possible ?

Comment: I'd love to see a body for that loop that allows for all possible method signatures and combinations of parameter values.